# iPhone to device via Wifi

Tags: iphone, sockets, embedded, bonjour

I have an embedded hardware device that currently broadcasts data via bluetooth. I don't want to go through the steps of the MFi program, so I'm thinking about using a different chip in my device to broadcast the same data via WiFi/UDP.

It is my understanding that in that case the only thing I need is sockets and bonjour for discovery.

My question is: do I need a third device in the equation (a wireless router where the two devices are connected)? Or can the two devices establish some sort of ad hoc network?

Pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WiFly from Roving Networks. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Just started using the WiFly modules from Roving Networks.  Works great!  Took me a little bit to realize that the devices ID is broadcast over UDP but the connection it wants is TCP.  AsyncSocket worked wonders for getting data to and from.